# How exactly does `R` define ARIMA models?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have trouble understanding the output of function `arima()` in `R`.

Reading the help file and other sources has not helped much...

Consider an AR(1) model as an example. As I understand it,

```
m1=arima(x, order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=TRUE)
```

estimates a model of the form

$$(x_t-\mu_x)=\varphi_0+\varphi_1(x_{t-1}-\mu_x)+\varepsilon_t$$

where $\mu_x$ is the mean of $x$. Since the population mean is not known, its sample counterpart $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} x_t$ is used.

However, I am **unable to reconstruct** $x$ from the fitted values and the residuals of the model, thus I must have misunderstood something. Here is what I do step-by-step:

```
T=1000; set.seed(1); x=rnorm(T, sd=10)         # generate a random variable x
m1=arima(x, order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=TRUE) # fit an AR(1) model for x
```

Obtain the $\varphi_0+\varphi_1(x_{t-1}-\mu_x)$:

```
fitted=(x-mean(x))*m1$coef[1] + 1*m1$coef[2]   # define fitted values from the AR(1) model
fitted=c(NA,fitted[-T])        # adjust so that fitted[t] corresponds to x[t] for any t
```

Obtain the $\varepsilon_t$:

```
resids=resid(m1)               # residuals from the AR(1) model
resids=c(NA,resids[-1])        # adjust so that resids[t] corresponds to x[t] for any t
```

Obtain the $(x_t-\mu_x)$:

```
true=x-mean(x)
```

Plot the $(x_t-\mu_x)$ in black and the $\varphi_0+\varphi_1(x_{t-1}-\mu_x)+\varepsilon_t$ in red:

```
plot( true[1:20], type="l" )
lines( (fitted+resids)[1:20], col="red" )
```

The two are **not equal!** (Although close, but likely more than purely due to an approximation error.)

**Edit:** Perhaps I should use $\frac{\varphi_0}{1-\varphi_1}$ instead of $\mu_x$, i.e. `m1$coef[2]/(1-m1$coef[1])` instead of `mean(x)`? I have tried that, too, and it did not help.

**Have I misinterpreted the model definition** (see how I define `true`, `fitted` and `resids`)**?**

---

By the way, I have no problem with the case of no constant term: `arima(..., include.mean=FALSE)`:

```
T=1000; set.seed(1); x=rnorm(T, sd=10)
m1=arima(x, order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=FALSE)
fitted=x[-T]*m1$coef[1]
resids=resid(m1)[-1]
plot(x[(1+1):(20+1)],type="l")
lines((fitted+resids)[1:20],col="red")
x[(1+1):(20+1)]==(fitted+resids)[1:20]
```

Comment: I now think there could have been a problem with including both {$\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$} *and* $\varphi_0$ in the first equation. Either the first two or the latter one should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Try using $\text{mean}(x)[1-φ_1]$ as the constant.

If you have $Y(t)-u=0.5\,Y(t-1)+e(t)$ this can be rewritten as

$$[1-.5B][Y(t)]=U+e(t)\,.$$

The general SARIMA equation with left-hand side constant $U$ is

$$ϕ(B)Φ(B^s)[Wt-U]= θ(B)Θ(B^s)Z_t$$

which can be restated as

$$ϕ(B)Φ(B^s)[W_t] = ϕ(B)Φ(B^s)[U]+ θ(B)Θ(B^s)Z_t\,.$$

For example if $Φ(B^s)=1$ and $ϕ(B)=[1-.4B]$ and $U= 10.0$ we obtain $$ϕ(B)Φ(B^s)[W_t] = 6+ θ(B)Θ(B^s)Z_t\,.$$

In general the conversion from the left-hand side constant to the right-hand side constant is the factor $ϕ(B)Φ(B^s)$. In general the conversion from the right-hand side constant to the left-hand side constant is the factor $[ϕ(B)Φ(B^s)]^{-1}$.